What are examples of English words containing a Near-close near-front unrounded vowel
What are examples of English words containing a near-close near-front unrounded vowel, when American pronunciation is used.

Although the question is simple, hopefully someone can type "English word examples near-close near-front unrounded vowel" into a computer search engine, and they can find this stack exchange posting.
IGLOO
ILL
ILLEGAL
IMAGINE
IMMEDIATE
IMPLY
IMPROVE
IN
INFANT
INLET
INN
INSECT
INTO
INVENT
ISSUE
IT


We usually don't mind self-answered questions that much, but this one seems particularly pointless. Why ask and answer this one?
